# Manifestation of chirality in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, chirality

I understand (I hope) the meaning of chirality but I am not really sure how does it affects the weak interaction. From what I understand, an electron is a superposition of left and right chirality electrons and when you measure the chirality, you pick one of them. So when an electron interacts with a W boson (let's say) does it pick a chirality and something happens only if the left chirality is chosen? Or if an electron gets out of a weak interaction, you are sure it is left handed? And in general, if you have an electron in lab, how can you find out it's chirality? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In general for fermions of spin $1/2$, the chirality is defined purely mathematically as under which representation of the Lorentz group the spinor field is transformed under $(1/2,0)$ or $(0,1/2)$ representation. From this point of view, direct experimental detection of chirality of the given particle is problematic.

However, there are some situations when it is possible to determine the chirality.

1) In massless limit, the chirality on the level of physical states coincides with helicity - the projection of momentum on the direction of motion. Both of these quantities are lorentz-invariant and conserved. This means that we know the chirality once we measure the particle's helicity, which is observable. Note that when the mass is non-zero, chirality is lorentz invariant but not conserved in time, while helicity is conserved in time but not lorentz-invariant, so they are not pretty good quantum numbers.

2) The representations $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$ separately are not parity invariant: under parity transformation, $(1/2,0)$ is converted into $(0,1/2)$, and vice versa. Therefore, a theory including parity violation in the fermion sector $\psi$ can contain only one chiral representation, which is achieved by introducing the chiral fields $\psi_{\pm} = \frac{1\mp \gamma_{5}}{2}\psi$. Together with masslessness of the SM neutrinos (which allows us to relate its helicity with chirality), this fact was used for constructing the gauge structure of the SM (see Wu experiment).

**"...Or if an electron gets out of a weak interaction, you are sure it is left handed? And in general, if you have an electron in lab, how can you find out it's chirality?.."**

Only left fermions interact with $W$-bosons. However, after the interaction you can't exactly define the chirality of the "emitted" electron, since it is massive and its chirality isn't conserved in time: even if initially there was only one chirality, with time it will be evolved into the superposition of chiralities. They may be some indirect methods to measure its chirality, but this is not a good idea.