# Are right-handed chiral particles more stable than left-handed?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, chirality

Are right-handed chiral particles usually more stable than left-handed because right-handed particles can't decay using W⁺/W⁻? For example, left-handed muons apparently decay most of the time in such a way that there is a virtual particle W⁻ involved, at least according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#Muon_decay) Wikipedia article. Since right-handed muons can't  decay this way, do they have longer lifetime?

Comment: Is there such a thing as a "right-handed chiral particle"? Even if there aren't any interactions that can change the chirality of a particular particle, there's nothing preventing every physical particle from being a superposition of the chirality eigenstates.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345473/manifestation-of-chirality-in-particle-physics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, narrowly speaking, right-chiral muons are stable as they don't decay through the charged weak current (the $W^-$ you mention). The electrons left-chiral muons decay to are also left chiral, a substantially useful handle in the calculation of muon decay rates.

The reason your question is so puzzling, bordering on insignificance,  is because left- and right-chiral muons (massive fermions in general), by dint of being massive, interconvert ferociously into each other as they propagate. 
In that sense, right-chiral muons are as unstable as they go.

Even their +/- helicity flips proportionately to their mass, then, a fact of major utility in charged pion decay, going through a *W*.

Comment: Indeed I forgot that a physical muon is a superposition of the two chiral eigenstates.